# Why is PHP displaying parsing error on sql query

Tags: php, sql

```
$rows = ( "SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `clientid` = '".$_SESSION['clientid']."' LIMIT 1" );
$result1 = ( "SELECT `serverid`, `ipid`, `name`, `game`, `status`, `online`, `slots`, `type`, `port` FROM `server` WHERE `clientid` = '".$_SESSION['clientid']."' ORDER BY `serverid`" );
$servers = array( );
while ( $rows1 = ( $result1 ) )
{
    if ( !empty( $rows1['ipid'] ) )
    {
        $rows2 = ( "SELECT `ip` FROM `ip` WHERE `ipid` = '".$rows1['ipid']."' LIMIT 1" );
        $rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 );
    }
    ( $servers, $rows1 );
}
```

so, i'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /path/to/index.php on line 10
```

live 10 is this one:

```
$rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 );
```

my friend gave me this php application so i'm not really familiar with the problem.

Comment: Hello, your post needs some more information. What is the code of index.php?

Comment: Why are there round braces around almost _everything_ to begin with …? Was this written by someone mostly familiar with a different lange that requires such a syntax?

Comment: Seriously, what are you trying to here? You make `$row1` a string; make `$result` a string; make `$row1` equal to `$result` in an `if` statement; if an array element of the string `$row1` is filled (it isn't) fill `$row2` with a string; then start wrapping these strings in brackets separated by commas. Are you aware no SQL query has actually been performed anywhere?

Comment: actually i have no idea what my friend tried here, he just gave me this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't support to union two expressions inside brackets:

```
$rows1 = ( $rows1, $rows2 );
```

So, it should be

```
$rows1 = new Array( $rows1, $rows2 );
```

or

```
$rows1 = $rows1.$rows2;
```